# Search for string in multiple columns without using OR - construction

Tags: sql, oracle

I wonder whether there is a better option to search for a string in several columns without using the or-construction.
Here is my code:

```
 SELECT 
   originaltktid,
   securityidentifier,
   ticker,
   customeraccountcounterparty,
   accountcounterpartyshortname,
   lastlogin,
   customertype,
   securityidentifier || ' ' || ticker || ' ' ||customeraccountcounterparty || ' ' ||accountcounterpartyshortname || ' ' ||lastlogin || ' ' ||customertype as SearchinString
 FROM bondtrades
 WHERE 1=1
 /* first option */
   AND securityidentifier || ' ' || ticker || ' ' ||customeraccountcounterparty || ' ' ||accountcounterpartyshortname || ' ' ||lastlogin || ' ' ||customertype like '%RAU%'
 /*second option
  * AND (securityidentifier like '%RAU%' 
  *  OR ticker like '%RAU%' 
  *  OR customeraccountcounterparty like '%RAU%'
  *  OR accountcounterpartyshortname like '%RAU%' 
  *  OR lastlogin '%RAU%'
  *  OR customertype like '%RAU%'
  */;
```

Happy for any idea. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the problem with using `OR`? (which is definitely better than concatenating the columns into a single string btw)

Comment: You can try this. `(instr(col1,'RAU') + instr(col2,'RAU') + ... + instr(colN,'RAU')) > 0` 
But oracle always try to do transformation called "or expansion". Transform "or" into union all querys with relevant condition.

Comment: You could extend your table with a [virtual column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1). You can define indexes on such columns, although there will be no benefit in your case, as you search substrings.

Comment: I like your second option better.  If any of your columns is null it will still work and as soon as it finds a match it can stop comparing for that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the REGEXP_LIKE function or a CASE statement. In my testing, the REGEXP_LIKE appears to be slightly more effecent when I use SQL Developers "Explain Plan" option using my own test data.

```
SELECT 
   originaltktid,
   securityidentifier,
   ticker,
   customeraccountcounterparty,
   accountcounterpartyshortname,
   lastlogin,
   customertype,
   securityidentifier || ' ' || ticker || ' ' ||customeraccountcounterparty || ' ' ||accountcounterpartyshortname || ' ' ||lastlogin || ' ' ||customertype as SearchinString
 FROM bondtrades
 WHERE 1=1
  /* Thrid option */
   AND REGEXP_LIKE(SECURITYIDENTIFIER || TICKER || CUSTOMERACCOUNTCOUNTERPARTY ||ACCOUNTCOUNTERPARTYSHORTNAME ||LASTLOGIN || CUSTOMERTYPE,'RAU');
 /* Fourth option   
    AND CASE WHEN SECURITYIDENTIFIER LIKE '%RAU%' THEN 1
        WHEN ticker LIKE '%RAU%' THEN 1
        WHEN customeraccountcounterparty LIKE '%RAU%' THEN 1
        WHEN accountcounterpartyshortname like '%RAU%' then 1
        WHEN lastlogin like '%RAU%' then 1
        WHEN customertype like '%RAU%' then 1
        ELSE 0
        end = 1
        /*;
```